# STS 3.9.5 AutoComplete does not work with roo

Tags: spring, eclipse, roo

I installed STS 3.9.5 with java 10 and the autocomplete stopped working for the Roo generated entities. For example, if I put in the Domain class the method set and  get, it works fine. If the method is in the AspectJ, the autocomplete is stopped.

I tried to install java 1.8 but the same problem exists. I installed on 2 different PCs and got into the same issue. If I use STS 3.9.0 , it's ok!!

Comment: I use STS 3.9.5.RELEASE and Roo 2.0.0.RELEASE with java 8 on OSX and it works. Maybe it's windows related?

Comment: i have spring roo 1.3.2

Comment: I can confirm it's ok using STS 3.9.0 and Spring Roo 1.3.2 The issue raises with STS 3.9.1+